# How do I remove white space on the left from a table in html

Tags: html, css

This is a two column table. On the left is an image and right text. On the right side there is no white space but on the left side there is space.

This is the HTML code I use :

```css
#text {
  width: 60%;
}

#digitalhelp {
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
}

.Banner {
  background-color: #2296EE;
  width: 1600px;
  height: 730px;
}

table #t1 {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

t1 tr td {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="Banner">
  <table id="t1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" ;>
    <tr>
      <td id="text">
        <p> Helloo </p>
      </td>
      <td> <img id="digitalhelp" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1454165804606-c3d57bc86b40?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=60" alt="Digital help" </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

The white space next to the "Hello" is what I am talking about
[image: The white space next to the "Hello" is what i am talking about]

Comment: you can try using `div` and `span` tag if its not mandatory to use table

Answer (score 0):

Comment your CSS line `#text{width: 60%;}`.. It will remove the whitespace.. It is because you set a width on the table column